# no text found web-scraping using Beautifulsoup4 python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to webscrape the calories of a fruit (prediction) using google search

```
def fetch_calories(prediction):
    try:
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?&q=calories+in+" + prediction
        req = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
        calories = soup.find("div", class_="BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd").text
        return calories

    except Exception as e:
        st.error("Can't able to fetch the Calories")
        print(e)
```

it runs finely before this but suddenly today it gives me this error

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I already the BeautifulSoup package using this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Google classes are dynamic, but it looks like some things are static. I think the following CSS selector might work: `div.kp-header div[role="heading"]`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this could be because the class_ attribute value has changed.
Could you check its value in the inspector?